# Iteratively applying time series model based on store-product in R using purrr/tidyverse

Tags: r, time-series, tidyverse, purrr

I have the following timeseries:

```
data = data.frame(Date=c('2017-01-01', '2017-02-01', '2017-03-01', '2017-04-01','2017-05-01','2017-06-01','2017-01-01', '2017-02-01', '2017-03-01', '2017-04-01','2017-05-01','2017-06-01','2017-01-01', '2017-02-01', '2017-03-01', '2017-04-01','2017-05-01','2017-06-01'),
                  store=c('A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','B','C','C','C','C','C','C'),
                  prod_id=c('p1','p2','p3','p4','p5','p6','p1','p2','p3','p4','p5','p6','p1','p2','p3','p4','p5','p6'),
                  sales=c('12.1','13','15','10','12','9.0','12.5','13.3','14.8','11','10','12.1','13','12.2','11','10.9','13.4','11.1'))

data

       Date     store  prod_id  sales
1  2017-01-01     A         p1   12.1
2  2017-02-01     A         p2     13
3  2017-03-01     A         p3     15
4  2017-04-01     A         p4     10
5  2017-05-01     A         p5     12
6  2017-06-01     A         p6    9.0
7  2017-01-01     B         p1   12.5
8  2017-02-01     B         p2   13.3
9  2017-03-01     B         p3   14.8
10 2017-04-01     B         p4     11
11 2017-05-01     B         p5     10
12 2017-06-01     B         p6   12.1
13 2017-01-01     C         p1     13
14 2017-02-01     C         p2   12.2
15 2017-03-01     C         p3     11
16 2017-04-01     C         p4   10.9
17 2017-05-01     C         p5   13.4
18 2017-06-01     C         p6   11.1
```

The unique values in the columns are:

```
sapply(data[c('Date','store','prod_id')],unique)

$Date
[1] "2017-01-01" "2017-02-01" "2017-03-01" "2017-04-01" "2017-05-01" "2017-06-01"

$store
[1] "A" "B" "C"

$prod_id
[1] "p1" "p2" "p3" "p4" "p5" "p6"
```

I want help in forecasting product sales store wise . Crude approach could be to use a for loop selecting each store first and within each store again have a for loop going through each product time series and forecasting for 1 period ahead.Can this process be made more efficient using nesting capabilities of purrr in tidyverse package ? (TS model:auto.arima from forecast package)

Comment: Aim is to understand purrr implementation. Auto.arima from forecast will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option - after converting the 'Date' to `Date` class, change the `nest`ed data by 'store' into `tsibble`, and generate the `model`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(fpp3)
library(tsibble)
data %>%
   mutate(Date = as.Date(Date)) %>%
   group_by(store) %>% 
  nest %>%
  mutate(data = map(data, ~ as_tsibble(.x, index = 'Date') %>% 
        model(arima = ARIMA(sales))))
```

Comment: how do you extract  forecasts and error metrics from the nested data?

Comment: The model is stored in a `list` column.  SO you can use `lapply` or `map` to loop over the `list` i.e. `lapply(out$data, function(x) x$<yourcolumn>)`